# Installing MySQL on CentOS throws error that cannot find mysqld.sock

Tags: centos, rhel, software-installation, mysql, services

I have `yum install mysql` in **CentOS 6.4**. Now, when I use `mysql` command, it throws the following error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
```

When I check the directory there is no mysql folder. How should I solve this problem? It's worth mentioning when I do `service mysql start` (or with `mysqld`) it errors **unrecognized service**.

I should mention that I have changed the path in `my.cnf` but nothing happens. The problem is that no `*.sock` file exists at all.

**Update**:

Results of checking mysql process with `mysqladmin -u root -p status` returns:

```
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' exists!
```

Also when I directly want to run `/etc/init.d/mysqld` it errors that it cannot resolve the ip (localhost.localdomain).

**Second Update:**

I have run the command `[root@localhost /]# rpm -qa | grep mysql`

and it returns:

```
mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64
mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.i686
mysql-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64
mysql-server-5.1.73-3.el6_5.i686
```

Comment: Did you start the mysql process? Is it running?

Comment: Have you tried changing path from "/var/run/..." to /var/lib/..." in my.cnf? Also, run `ps aux | grep mysql`

Comment: Check if you have this line in /etc/hosts  `127.0.0.1  localhost.localdomain`

Comment: and give us a my.cnf

Answer (score 0):

If your file my.cnf (usually in the /etc/mysql/ folder) is correctly configured with

`socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock`

you can check if mysql is running with the following command:

`mysqladmin -u root -p status`

try changing your permission to mysql folder. If you are working locally, you can try:

`sudo chmod -R 755 /var/lib/mysql/`

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376427/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-mysql-mysql-sock-38)

Comment: please see the question is updated

Comment: And it's worth I'm root user. No need for chmod

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just installed MySQL client not the server. Use the command below to install the server `yum install mysql-server`

Also you can refer the link for more information:- [MySQL](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/installing-mysql-server-on-centos)

Comment: I have installed it. Look at my updated question. Thanks you

Comment: check the binding of MySQL using the command lsof -i:3306 may be it's not listening on localhost